# Elastic Beanstalk HTTP to HTTPS Redirect In Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

We have a beanstalk

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment"
```

and we need the HTTP listener to redirect to HTTPS
now normally you'd just create a load balancer listener rule (as the answers on here suggest) like this

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "redirect_http_to_https" {
  listener_arn = XXX
  action {
    type = "redirect"
    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      host        = "#{host}"
      path        = "/#{path}"
      query       = "#{query}"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
  condition {}
}
```

However we, for reasons, have to use the built in beanstalk load balancer and not create our own load balancer resource, and as you see above i can't see that it's possible to target the beanstalks-loadbalancers-listener.
Instead i've tried to manipulate the settings options to configure the load balancer like this

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:default"
    name      = "Rules"
    value     = "redirect"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listenerrule:redirect"
    name      = "Process"
    value     = "443"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listenerrule:redirect"
    name      = "Priority"
    value     = "1"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
    name      = "Protocol"
    value     = "HTTPS"
  }
```

but none take effect. has anyone done it this way before? if not we'll have to do the redirection on the server probably in code.

This of course is so easy in the UI, took me less than 2 mins, but in terraform it's proving difficult

Comment: If you've managed to do it in the console and it works then the normal approach is to then run the plan and see what Terraform wants to undo. You then put those changes back into Terraform and the plan should be empty. Does this not work for you for some reason?

Comment: I've already did it, not exactly it. My redirect response are made by nginx inside the ec2 instance, created using ebextension file. I'll use the response to provides you the code of ebextension file. Please, don't vote down in my answer, it is because here I cant send formatted code.

Comment: Check this answer here: https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment/issues/98#issuecomment-804371372
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Already referenced by @jang00 in the comment above, but I think it deserves to be posted explicitly:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "main" {
  name = var.environment
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.main.name
  solution_stack_name = data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack.multi_container_docker.name

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "VPCId"
    value = var.vpc_id
    resource = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "Subnets"
    value = join(", ", [var.private_a_subnet_id, var.private_b_subnet_id])
    resource = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "ELBSubnets"
    value = join(", ", [var.public_a_subnet_id, var.public_b_subnet_id])
    resource = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = "${var.application_name}-service-elasticbeanstalk-instance-${var.environment}"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "InstanceType"
    value = var.instance_type
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "LoadBalancerType"
    value = "application"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name = "SystemType"
    value = "enhanced"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
    name = "ListenerEnabled"
    value = var.acm_eu_west_2.arn == "" ? "false" : "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
    name = "Protocol"
    value = "HTTPS"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
    name = "SSLCertificateArns"
    value = var.acm_eu_west_2.arn
  }
}

data "aws_lb_listener" "http_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.main.load_balancers[0]
  port = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "redirect_http_to_https" {
  listener_arn = data.aws_lb_listener.http_listener.arn
  priority = 1

  action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port = "443"
      protocol = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

See [this comment](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment/issues/98#issuecomment-804371372) in the terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've already did not exactly it, but it works for us. My redirect response are made by nginx inside the EC2 instances, created using ebextension file.

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
```